# controls styles in vb.net appearing like windows xp

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Windows 10 and making my program in visual studio 2017 some of my controls, like : monthcalendar, datetimepicker, etc... are appearing with Windows xp style.

[its appearing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiEt7.png)

and whant it to look like Windows 10 style

Any ideas why?

Comment: Under "Windows application framework properties" do you have `Enable XP Visual styles` selected?

Comment: That is not even XP style. That design goes back to Windows 2000 (as the last OS having it as default) ;).

Comment: in c# you go to Program.cs and make sure that `Application.EnableVisualStyles(); ` is there, not too sure for vb.net thought, might be along the same lines

Comment: @braX Enabled and it worked , thanks